# Google Calendar API return date, time and event name to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

banging my head against the wall with Google's calendar API. My calendar is public, with the address of:

```
 9p79sl2a31qgqfvjkfkupdbf8o@group.calendar.google.com
```

I want to access the 10 closest events in the future, and put their date, time and event name onto my page. I'm trying to access this as follows:

```
 var url = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/9p79sl2a31qgqfvjkfkupdbf8o@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=10&futureevents=true&alt=json'

 $.get(url, function(data){
    console.log(data);
 });
```

This correctly accesses my calendar data, but for some bizarre reason doesn't let me access my events' date and times, just the event name.

Can anyone shed some light on this? The calendar sharing settings are fully public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a different endpoint. I was successfully able to make a call and get the list back (including event names, dates, and a lot of other details.

For example:

```
{

   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"2814404343670000\"",
   "id": "bpgo6gtet1ao8j73kn770e6r20",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YnBnbzZndGV0MWFvOGo3M2tuNzcwZTZyMjAgOXA3OXNsMmEzMXFncWZ2amtma3VwZGJmOG9AZw",
   "created": "2014-08-04T06:25:51.000Z",
   "updated": "2014-08-05T01:29:31.835Z",
   "summary": "Startup leadership women",
   "creator": {
    "email": "qceventscalendar@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Sean Qian"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "9p79sl2a31qgqfvjkfkupdbf8o@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Queens Collective Events",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2014-08-05T18:00:00+10:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2014-08-05T21:00:00+10:00"
   },
   "iCalUID": "bpgo6gtet1ao8j73kn770e6r20@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  } ...
```

In order to make the call, use the following endpoint:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/9p79sl2a31qgqfvjkfkupdbf8o%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Pass that GET url into your AJAX call (obviously switching API_KEY with your actual key). 
You can get your api key from: https://console.developers.google.com

If you don't have an API account set up, I would go and create one, and use the Google Calendar API. It will make your life much easier. Keep in mind, you may have to add your testing server (localhost?) to Google's API settings in order for the call to return successfully.

If you need help let me know, I've played around with the Cal API quite a bit lately...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks mate, appreciate it.

Comment: Quick follow-up, in my original query I returned 10 results in the future, in ascending order. In your query these params no longer work, it just returns all events in any order. Can't see any info on restricting results on the API reference, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you will want to pass a parameter of orderBy: starttime as well as singleEvents=true. Check out this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/9p79sl2a31qgqfvjkfkupdbf8o%40group.calendar.google.com/events?orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: If for some reason that's not working though your fallback option is to write a function that takes the results and sorts them yourself however you need. This can be tuned as finely as you need. If you go this route you will probably need to use a date parser to compare date stamps from the different calendar events returned.